# What impact on layout does duplex printing have?

Tags: layout, printing

All printing apis that I've found lets the application know if the print job is set for duplex printing, and if so, which page edge is being used.

But none give any explanation of how your code should react in response to this fact. How does duplex printing affect the layout of documents?